# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void | Observable<User>'. ts(2339)

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscribe

```js
login() {
    this.auth.login(this.userName, this.password).subscribe((_: any) => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('app', {replaceUrl: true});
    });
  }
```

I dont know why i get this error, tried a few things but nothing works.

This here is my auth.login method - don’t know where the error could be - I am pretty new to Angular:

```js
login(username: string, password: string) {
  let userObject: User;
    if (username === 'user' && password === 'user1234') {
      userObject = {
        name: 'Max Mustermann',
        userRole: 'USER',
      };
    }
    else if (username === 'admin' && password === 'admin1234') {
      userObject = {
        name: 'Erika Mustermann',
        userRole: 'ADMIN',
      };
    }else{
      return this.assertNever();
    }
    return of(userObject).pipe(
      tap(user => {
        Storage.set({ key: TOKEN_KEY, value: JSON.stringify(user) });
        this.currentUser.next(user);
      })
    );
  }
```

When deleting the assertNever() method, I get this error at the last `return`:

> Variable 'userObject' is used before being assigned. ts(2454)

Comment: could you pls add the code of the  `auth.login` method?

Comment: I agree with @akotech (your channel looks great, by the way, I just subscribed to it!)

Comment: This looks hard to answer without knowing how `assertNever` looks like.

Comment: @JuanVicenteBerzosaTejero thx m8! appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because the your **'login' method should has a path which does not have a "return"**.

The others paths indeed should be returning an "Observable", which sounds good.

EDIT:

Now that I can see your code, it seems that the error locates in this line:

```
return this.assertNever();
```

Could "assertNever()" method return "void"/null/nothing???

Any way, in order to avoid the error, could you fake a dummy user and return it changing this line:

```
else {
      \\return this.assertNever();
      userObject = {
        name: 'Fake',
        userRole: 'NOLOGGED',
      };
}
```

Comment: Yes, assertNever(); basically just throws an Error. If I try to do it without the "return this.assertNever();", I get the error variable 'userObject' is used before being assigned.ts(2454)

Comment: Yes, because you don't have 'userObjec't created, just declared, so it would be undefined. Could be the posibility that you treat it as a "fake user not allowed" of something like that, instead throw an exception? Just something similar to what I've just edit.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some return types to your functions will help you in the future. From what I can see, your function `this.assertNever();` always throws but is declared (or inferred) to return void.

Change its declaration to return `never` and TS will recognize that this function will not return.

void = returns, but does not return a value
never = will not return / return vaue will not be observable